# issue with stashing in git

Tags: git, github

I am always getting the following error:

```
 needs merge
 needs merge
 unmerged (54999d1140216fbaaf8606a667fd15f7a286633a)
 unmerged (03087759b4c28212a759b3c60835645cdd211023)
 unmerged (fc4c2ab5de797dc38b7e636f63077590d7dd1daa)
```

whenever I try to do git stash. I basically had made some changes to the branch, but I want to discard all of it and just pull out from remote. How do I do this? Tried doing `git reset --hard HEAD` and it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have merge conflicts in your tree. I expect that `git stash` is bailing because it doesn't have any way to record a merge conflict. In any case, what do you mean when you say `git reset --hard HEAD` doesn't work? That command discards all local changes and resets the working tree and index back to HEAD. What part of that "doesn't work"?

If you actually need to discard all your commits and make `HEAD` identical to a remote branch, just run `git fetch` and then `git reset --hard remote/branch` (e.g. if you're trying to reset back to `origin/master` then it would be `git reset --hard origin/master`).